# On Screen Keyboard auto pop up

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, auto-populate, on-screen-keyboard

Is there a way to on screen keyboard auto pop up when user clicks TextBox field on WPF?
If it is possible, can it work across the app?

Answer (score 1):

On TextBox focus  you can use

XAML

```
<TextBox Name="TxtBxName" GotFocus="TxtBxName_GotFocus" />
```

C#

```
private void TxtBxName_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Process[] pname = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
    if (pname.Length == 0)
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Launch("osk.exe");
}
```

to invoke the on-screen keyboard application that comes with Windows

Same way on the lost focus you should terminate the process

Comment: also check to see if it is already not running, otherwise you will end up running multiple instances if focus is regained multiple times. it would be better to close the process when focus shifts away from textbox

Comment: may be silly question, but how do i use it within Focus()?

Comment: it opens small keyboard. I want standard tablet one.

Comment: If you are planing to run the app on the devices it would automatically do when the cursor reaches in the textbox and if in case you are running the app on the windows it is the default keyboard available with the windows which could be used.

Comment: problem is, it doesn't launch touch keyboard on windows 10 tablet when cursor is in textbox

Comment: I think you need to ask the question in little more details. Now the scenario is changed. Lemme see if i can find something for you

Answer (score 0):

I have put together all your answers and what works for what me is:

```
    private void OpenOSK()
    {
        try
        {
            Process.Start("TabTip.exe");
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }

    private void _textBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenOSK();
    }
```